# Is it possible to make a responsive web page with using Ext JS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, extjs

I am designing a web page with using **Ext JS** (I am using ext js for a few weeks so I am not expert). I want to design it **[responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)** but I coundnt find a solution? Is there a way to design page like this? Also i wonder if I use bootstrap css to do this, it can be problem?

```
<link href="ext-js/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I am using this Ext-all.css but it does not giving that functionality. 
Is there a proper code block to do that?

Comment: @Leo how can i do that?

Comment: Why it's not responsive?

Comment: @Leo because Ext JS doesnt have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching about viewport...

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport

Comment: thank you so much i got a solution with using viewport.

Answer (score 2):

```
listeners: {
            resize: function(panel, w, h) {
                    var viewport = panel.up(viewport);
                    var detailpanel = panel.down('#detailpanel');
                    var gridpanel = panel.down('#gridPanel');
                    gridpanel.setHeight(h-70);
                    detailpanel.setHeight(h-70);
                    if (w<500){
                            panel.hide();
                    }
                    else{
                            panel.setVisible('true');
                    }
            }
    }
```

You can find more information [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?247473-Changing-layout-accoring-to-viewport-dimensions-%28responsive-design-%29)

Comment: It isn't easy to customize ExtJS 4. for custom responsive features. ExtJS 5 will support responsive design of the layout (you can find a beta in official site).

Comment: And if you really need a lot of responsive feature the best option is AngularJs.